# Does Azure devops server support cargo packages from crates.io upstream

Tags: rust, azure-devops, rust-cargo, rust-crates

Which version of azure devops server supports upstream artifact feed from crates.io ?

We are running Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1 RC2 installed on-prem
We are planning to store Cargo artifacts and download Crates of rust libraries to Azure artifacts repository.

Do I need to upgrade in order to get support for Cargo upstream feed? which version supports it?

Comment: According to the online doco, on premises versions don't support it, and the Azure version has it in preview https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/start-using-azure-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=cargo%2Cnugetserver%2Cnugettfs#feature-availability https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-cargo?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the **Cargo** related features (include **Cargo** type of packages and **`crates.io`** is available as an upstream source) are only supported on Azure Artifacts of Azure DevOps Services and not on that of Azure DevOps Server/TFS.

The **Cargo** features were released to Azure DevOps Services in August 2023. And currently, it still is a public preview instead of generally available (GA) version on Azure DevOps Services.

Typically, the new features are introduced on Azure DevOps Services first, and then might be available for on-premises Azure DevOps Server/TFS.

Currently, there is not a timeline of when the **Cargo** features can be available on Azure DevOps Server/TFS.

Related documentations:

- [**Introducing Azure Artifacts support for Cargo Crates (public preview)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2023/sprint-226-update#introducing-azure-artifacts-support-for-cargo-crates-public-preview)
- [**Azure DevOps Released Features**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline-released)
- [**Azure DevOps Roadmap**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline)

---